# CORS issue when calling endpoints/webapi from vue application

Tags: cors, vuejs3, asp.net-core-webapi

Ok, so I have a webapi on .netcore 3.1 on my local machine and also a separate vue3-site on the same machine. The webapi starts up on https://localhost/44347 and the vue3-site starts up on http://localhost:8080.

So first when trying to call the very first "get"-endpoint that I need to get some info to render a "questionnaire" I ran into the classic CORS-issue:

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44347/api/questionnaire/getQuestions' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I managed to get around that issue by adding the following code to my Startup.cs for the webapi:

```
// ConfigureServices:
services.AddCors();
services.AddCors(options =>
{      
  options.AddPolicy(_corsPolicy, builder =>
  {    
    builder
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader();
  });
});

 // Configure:

 app.UseCors(options => 
   options.SetIsOriginAllowed(x => _ = true)
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials()
  );
 app.UseAuthorization();

 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
 {      
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "default",
      pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
 });
```

So then I got further so now the user can answer some questions in the questionnaire but now I run into another CORS-issue when calling a POST on my webapi to save the questions the user answered:

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44347/api/questionnaire/saveAnswers' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

So it's a slightly different CORS-error that mentions "preflight" but it's not the same as before. I don't get why this wouldn't work when I got past the first CORS-issue by adding that code in Startup.cs....

EDIT: Added below client code to example:

My get and post methods using axios are configured like so:
import axios from "axios";
import {Promise} from "core-js";

```
const baseUrl = "https://localhost:44347";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

const axiosGeneric = {
  axiosGet(url) { 
  return axios
  .get(`${baseUrl}${url}`)
  .then(response => {
    return response;
  })
  .catch(error => {       
    return this.handleError(`${baseUrl}${url}`, error);
  });
},

axiosPost(url, payload) {    
  return axios.post(`${baseUrl}${url}`, payload).then(response => {
    if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 204) {
      if (response) return response;
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(response.message);
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    return this.handleError(`${baseUrl}${url}`, error);
  });
},
```

I have also tried dressing the HttpGet and HttpPost in the webapi with/without the [Authorize] attribute, for example:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("questionnaire/getquestions")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetQuestions() { ... }
```

But regardless of whether I use [Authorize] or not the get always works and the post does not.

I'd really appreciate any and all suggestions!

Comment: Please describe the preflight request or add the relevant client code.

Comment: I don't know why you don't have `app.UseCors("policyName")` but I think it's better to have it following the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Besides, do you have an authentication scheme for the post request? We have this words `The OPTIONS requests are always anonymous` in [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference#cors-preflight-request), so if the post request requires authentication, then preflight may not get correct response, and causing cors issue

Comment: @jub0bs I added the client code to the example, thx!

Comment: @TinyWang I've tried so many variants of app.UseCors, with policy, without and the example I posted was the one I got to work. But I can try adding a policy again to see if it helps. This whole "preflight" terminology is new to me. I've worked 99% with .net projects where the clientpages are in the same project/site during development so I've had the luck never to run into much CORS issues before. :)

Comment: thank you for your reply, and if you are sure there's an authentication for the post request, you might enable anonymous for the request for test purpose.

Comment: Your client sends credentialed requests `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;` but you have not allowed credentialed access in your CORS config. That cannot work.

Comment: @jub0bs I have now added "AllowCredentials" (I think) in my Configure-method in Startup.js, see my updated answer. I still experience the same behavior though, the call to the "get"-method works but I still get CORS-error when calling the "post"-method... Am I configuring app.UserCors incorrectly? Thx!